# Publish Unprotected API on wso2 api manager 3.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am looking forward to having an API that is not protected by OAuth or basic Application Level Security. How to publish an unprotected API on WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the security of the Resource in api publisher as shown below.

[image]

You need to un-set the security of all the resources in order to make the full API unprotected.